PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Kohana_Cache_Exception [ 0 ]: PHP APC extension is not available
after a migration from ubuntu 18;04 to 20.04, my php site comes up with an error in the apache logs
 [Tue Apr 23 23:09:52.521788 2024] [:error] [pid 4026] [client 10.164.136.69:39608] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Kohana_Cache_Exception [ 0 ]: PHP APC extension is not available. ~ MODPATH/cache/classes/kohana/cache/apc.php [ 52 ]\n  thrown in /var/www/*/cache/apc.php on line 52


when I check in the file at line 52, this is what I get
 48         protected function __construct(array $config)
 49         {
 50                 if ( ! extension_loaded('apc'))
 51                 {
 52                         throw new Kohana_Cache_Exception('PHP APC extension is not available.');
 53                 }
 54
 55                 parent::__construct($config);
 56         }


any idea where the problem might be coming from?
by default the site was on php 5.6, after migration to ubuntu 20.04, php 7 was installed by default, I ran commands to switch php 7.4 to 5.6 but no change

This is just a question of installing the right version of your extension depending on your OS and your PHP version. Can you post the result of a phpinfo() and the lines related to your extensions from your php.ini?

when i trying to find APC extension in php.ini, i can't find it

i solved my problem with this command line
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5.6-apcu

Add or ensure the following line exists in the php.ini file:
extension=apcu.so

restart apache
sudo service apache2 restart



phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.6.40-57+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
System => Linux "host" 5.15.0-1061-azure #70~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon
Apr 8 15:38:58 UTC 2024 x86_64 Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled Configuration File (php.ini)
Path => /etc/php/5.6/cli Loaded Configuration File =>
/etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini Scan this dir for additional .ini files =>
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d Additional .ini files parsed =>
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-bcmath.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-bz2.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-imagick.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/5.6/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
PHP API => 20131106 PHP Extension => 20131226 Zend Extension =>
220131226 Zend Extension Build => API220131226,NTS PHP Extension Build
=> API20131226,NTS Debug Build => no Thread Safety => disabled Zend Signal Handling => disabled Zend Memory Manager => enabled Zend
Multibyte Support => provided by mbstring IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => enabled
Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, glob,
data, http, ftp, compress.bzip2, phar Registered Stream Socket
Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv2, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1,
tlsv1.2 Registered Stream Filters => zlib., string.rot13,
string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.,
consumed, dechunk, bzip2., convert.iconv., mcrypt., mdecrypt.


While answering your question is generally okay and perhaps even encouraged, you should have edited your first reply with this information.
